# Агрегация в Clickhouse

Tags: sql, postgresql, clickhouse

Есть ли в Clickhouse аналог array_agg из PostgreSQL? Пытаюсь получить из таблицы:

```
id    text     pid      date
1   "Текст1"    1   "2020-01-01"
2   "Текст2"    3   "2010-01-01"
3   "Текст1"    2   "2020-10-01"
4   "Текст1"    3   "2015-07-03"
5   "Текст2"    4   "2014-09-07"
```

таблицу:

```
  text        min_date        max_date     array_agg
"Текст1"    "2015-07-03"    "2020-10-01"    {1,2,3}
"Текст2"    "2010-01-01"    "2014-09-07"    {3,4}
```

В postgresql работает запрос `select text, min(date), max(date), array_agg(pid) from table group by text`. С Clickhouse как это заменить - непонятно.
Читал про -ForEach, но он вроде просто преобразует агрегатную функцию.

Comment: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/ru/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/groupuniqarray/

Comment: @AzizUmarov, большое спасибо. Заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на [данную](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/ru/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/groupuniqarray/) функцию.

**groupUniqArray**

> Синтаксис: groupUniqArray(x) или
> groupUniqArray(max_size)(x)
>
> Составляет массив из различных значений аргумента. Расход оперативной
> памяти такой же, как у функции uniqExact.
>
> Функция groupUniqArray(max_size)(x) ограничивает размер
> результирующего массива до max_size элементов. Например,
> groupUniqArray(1)(x) равнозначно [any(x)].

Comment: Да, я в итоге ее и использовал. Не знаю, в чем дело, я ее еще до того как задать вопрос применял также, как и сейчас, но она просто не работала. Сейчас же все нормально (за исключением того, что кликхаусу памяти не хватает).

Comment: Главное что заработало бывает и не такое

Answer (score 1):

Скорее подходит функция [groupArray](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/grouparray/):

```sql
select text, min(date), max(date), groupArray(pid) array_agg
from table 
group by text
```