# Использование формирующихся массивов во время выполнения sql запроса

Tags: sql, postgresql

В продолжение предыдущего вопроса ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205926/Агрегация-в-clickhouse/1206119#1206119](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205926/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-clickhouse/1206119#1206119)), пытаюсь найти способ использовать информацию из сформированного массива.
Из таблицы:

```
id    text     pid      date
1   "Текст1"    1   "2020-01-01"
2   "Текст2"    3   "2010-01-01"
3   "Текст1"    2   "2020-10-01"
4   "Текст1"    3   "2015-07-03"
5   "Текст2"    4   "2014-09-07"
```

С помощью запроса `select text, min(date), max(date), array_agg(pid) from table group by text` получается следующий результат:

```
 text        min_date        max_date     array_agg
"Текст1"    "2015-07-03"    "2020-10-01"    {1,2,3}
"Текст2"    "2010-01-01"    "2014-09-07"    {3,4}
```

Как нужно модифицировать запрос, чтобы из array_agg найти pid, имеющий самую "свежую" дату, получая такую таблицу:

```
 text        min_date        max_date     array_agg   last_pid
"Текст1"    "2015-07-03"    "2020-10-01"    {1,2,3}       2
"Текст2"    "2010-01-01"    "2014-09-07"    {3,4}         4
```

last_pid равен 4 во второй строке из-за того, что все еще происходит группировка по text. Собственно вопрос в том, можно ли как-то делать некий внутренний запрос, используя формирующийся массив, учитывая внешнюю группировку по text?

Comment: *из array_agg найти pid, имеющий самую "свежую" дату* В промежуточной таблице отсутствует необходимая информация. Задача нерешаема. Получайте нужные данные на основании исходной таблицы. Используйте FIRST_VALUE().

Comment: Можно подробнее, для чего используется FIRST_VALUE()?

Comment: Эта функция позволяет извлечь значение одного поля из первой записи при сортировке по другому полю. [Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       "text", 
       MIN("date") OVER (PARTITION BY "text"), 
       MAX("date") OVER (PARTITION BY "text"), 
       ARRAY_AGG("pid") OVER (PARTITION BY "text"),
       FIRST_VALUE("pid") OVER (PARTITION BY "text" ORDER BY "date" DESC)
FROM "table"
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Буду теперь разбираться, что тут происходит. Про оконные функции в sql вообще впервые увидел.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш запрос с одной добавкой и без оконных функции:

```sql
select 
    "text", min("date"), max("date"), array_agg(pid),
    (array_agg(pid order by "date" desc))[1] as last_pid,
 from "table"
 group by "text";
```